# I'm trying to use scripting bridge with iTunes, but I'm getting an error

Tags: itunes, class-method, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to use scripting bridge to access album artwork with iTunes, but when I use the method

```
[iTunesApplication currentTrack];
```

I get an error saying that there is no know class method *current track*

It seems to work in other people's code, so what am I doing wrong? I don't think I'm trying to call it as a class method.

Answer (score 1):

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
[iTunes currentTrack];
```

should work.